# calling a type bound procedure in a PURE procedure Fortran

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

If I have declared type like

```
 type test(NSIZE)
  integer, len :: NSIZE
  real :: dummy(NSIZE)
  contains 
  procedure, pass(this) :: proc 

  end test
  type(test(NSIZE=10)) :: test_type
```

my `proc` subroutine is PURE. My proc returns say one value and does not have any side effects.

```
 pure subroutine proc(this, n) 
  implicit none 
 class(test(NSIZE=*)), intent(inout) :: this 
 integer, intent(inout) :: n
    n = n +1 
 end subroutine proc
```

Now inside another subroutine also declared as PURE I call proc

```
  pure subroutine test2 

    integer :: n 

     call  test_type% proc(n)
  end subroutine test2
```

I get the error on the `call  test% proc(n)` saying following:

`error #7140: This global use associated object appears in a 'defining' context in a PURE procedure or in an internal procedure contained in a PURE procedure.`

**A self contained example**

```
module mod1
   implicit none

      type test (size)
         integer, len :: size
         real :: dum(size)
      contains
         procedure, pass(this) :: dum_proc
      end type

      type(test(size=10)) :: test1

   contains

      pure subroutine dum_proc(this,  n )
         implicit none
         class(test(size=*)), intent(inout) :: this
         integer, intent(out) :: n
         n =n +2
      end subroutine dum_proc
end module mod1


program SUPPORT


implicit none
integer :: n

n = 0

call caller(n)


contains
   pure subroutine caller( nk )
   use mod1, only : test1
   implicit none

   integer, intent(inout) :: nk

   call test1% dum_proc(nk)

   end subroutine

end program SUPPORT`
```

Comment: `test` is a type in the first fragment, and an object in the second.  Show your actual code.

Comment: I have updated my question, thanks

Comment: But what is the `test` that you use in ` call  test% proc(n)`? Where does it come from? Show us a [mcve], nut just a few lines.

Comment: Sorry,, I meant as that `test` has been declared with type `test`. I see that is confusing. I have put the declaration and called it now `test_type% `

Comment: I have added an example which you can copy and directly compile. It should give the error mentioned in the thread. Does anyone know why this error appears and how to solve/overcome it

Comment: Exactly as the error message says, you shall not modify global variables in pure subprograms. We may have a duplicate.

Comment: Where Am I changing a global variable?!

Comment: I think it is not an *exact* duplicate after all, but I think it is useful to leave it linked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53556047/fortran-pure-functions

Comment: The lesson learnt from here is that when calling a type bound procedure, it is possible to change a member of the type itself, which then breaks the `pure` rule if that type is defined globally.
Despite being aware of the `pure` rules, it was not clear to me that the type bound procedure will break that rule also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem comes from the call

```
call test1% dum_proc(nk)
```

Because `test1` in the pure subroutine `caller` has been use associated it is not allowed to be an actual argument corresponding to a dummy argument with the `intent(inout)` attribute.  In the call to the type-bound procedure `test1` *is* associated with the passed-object dummy argument `this` (with that intent).

Being associated with an `intent(inout)` dummy argument counts as a variable definition context, and it is this that "'defining' context" means in the error message.  It isn't necessary for the argument actually to be changed for it to be in a defining context.

If, instead, you have `test1` as an `intent(inout)` dummy argument this restriction does not apply.  Having `test1` *host* associated has the same restriction as if use associated.

Comment: Ahhh, this makes sense. So the best option will be to have a wrapper around `caller` which passes to `caller` the object `test1` as intent(inout) and then do the call to `dum_proc`.

Comment: You can pass `test1` as an `intent(inout)` argument to `caller` and then it is not subject to the same restriction.